# How to test our application to be compatible with underlying technology changes?

Tags: quality-assurance, application-software-testing, compatibility-testing

I have a JAVA based web application, where Tomcat is used as web application server and MySQL as Database. How do I test my application if there is any technology updates ?

For example, if there is MySQL DB update planned from version X to Y or if tomcat or JDK update is planned from x version to y version. How do I check if the changes in the update will affect my applications functionality, performance .. etc.?

Answer (score 0):

To ensure the compatibility of your JAVA based web application with underlying technology changes, you can follow these steps:

1. Develop a test plan: Start by developing a comprehensive test plan that outlines the objectives of your testing efforts. Make sure you have a clear understanding of the changes that are being made, and the areas of your application that are most likely to be affected.
2. Test in a controlled environment: Set up a controlled test environment that is isolated from your production environment. This will allow you to perform tests without affecting live data or production systems.
3. Test compatibility with new technology versions: Use the test environment to test your application with the new technology versions. For example, install the new version of Tomcat or MySQL and run your application to check if it is functioning as expected.
4. Test functional and performance: Ensure that your application is still working as expected and there are no changes to its functional behavior. You can also test performance aspects such as response time and resource usage to determine if there have been any performance degradation.
5. Test with real data: Test your application with real data to ensure that the new technology updates have not caused any data loss or corruption.
6. Document test results: Document the results of your tests, including any issues or bugs that you encounter. This documentation can be used to provide feedback to the development team and help improve the compatibility of your application with future technology updates.
7. Perform regression testing: Once your application has been updated to work with the new technology, perform regression testing to ensure that no new bugs have been introduced.

By following these steps, you can help ensure that your JAVA based web application is compatible with underlying technology changes and continues to function as expected.

Comment: Appreciate your response and thought flow over here. Can you please comment difference between point no. 4 and 7, except the performance testing part. 

When you say, "Ensure that your application is still working as expected and there are no changes to its functional behavior." Do you mean to execute smoke or sanity test suite here?

Comment: Yes, the steps 4 and 7 are similar in terms of their objective, which is to ensure that the application is still working as expected after the technology updates. The difference lies in the scope of the testing.

Step 4 is focused on checking the functional behavior of the application and ensuring that there are no changes to its functional behavior. This could involve executing smoke tests or sanity tests to check the basic functionality of the application, as well as more detailed functional tests to check specific features and functionality.

Comment: Step 7, on the other hand, is focused on performing regression testing. Regression testing is a type of testing that is performed to ensure that changes to the code or technology updates have not introduced any new bugs or broken existing functionality. The scope of regression testing is usually wider than smoke or sanity testing and covers a larger set of tests that have been previously executed.

Comment: In summary, step 4 is focused on checking the functional behavior of the application after the technology updates, while step 7 is focused on verifying that the changes to the code or technology updates have not impacted the existing functionality.